# BULK INSERT and the dreaded ü

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, utf-8, insert

I have a system that uploads some data from a .CSV file. One of the records now has some data that contains the letter `ü` (`Ertürk`). When it gets uploaded to SQL it shows as `Ert³rk`. Now I believe that this is an issue that can be solved by setting the character set to utf8 and this can be done with a SQL command. I don't know a whole lot about this so I'm asking for some help here. using MS SQL Server 2008

My SQL command is simply:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.database from 'C:\Myfolder\Myfile.csv'
```

Is there something I can add or change to this to allow it to process my `ü` properly?

Thanks

Comment: Please tag dbms product used, since the answer may depend on it.

Comment: Did you try specifying a codepage in your statement?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: Add `WITH (CODEPAGE = 850)`, or whatever codepage your CSV file is using. Note that UTF-8 is not supported.

Comment: Excellent - adding CODEPAGE = 1252 worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the codepage of the text file you are importing, for example:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.database from 'C:\Myfolder\Myfile.csv' WITH (CODEPAGE = 850)
```

make sure to replace 850 by the actual codepage of your text file.